# How to reopen bokeh html file and restore the last zoomed status of every figures?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a html file generated by `bokeh` `gridplot` which contains multiple figures.

Suppose I open the html file, zoomed-in some (or all) figures to different levels and then closed the file. Next time when I reopen this file, I want all figures automatically set to the previous zoomed-level.

Could you please show me how to do it?

Here is an example code to quickly generate a html file with two figures.

```py
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import save
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.plotting import figure

x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save,box_select"

p1 = figure(title="Legend Example", tools=TOOLS)

p1.circle(x, y, legend_label="sin(x)")
p1.circle(x, 2 * y, legend_label="2*sin(x)", color="orange")
p1.circle(x, 3 * y, legend_label="3*sin(x)", color="green")

p1.legend.title = "Markers"

p2 = figure(title="Another Legend Example", tools=TOOLS)

p2.circle(x, y, legend_label="sin(x)")
p2.line(x, y, legend_label="sin(x)")

p2.line(
    x,
    2 * y,
    legend_label="2*sin(x)",
    line_dash=(4, 4),
    line_color="orange",
    line_width=2,
)

p2.square(x, 3 * y, legend_label="3*sin(x)", fill_color=None, line_color="green")
p2.line(x, 3 * y, legend_label="3*sin(x)", line_color="green")

p2.legend.title = "Lines"
p2.x_range = p1.x_range

save(gridplot([p1, p2], ncols=2, width=400, height=400))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you can use Bokeh's ResetTool and the CustomJS callback to store the zoom levels in the browser's local storage and retrieve them when the HTML file is opened again.

Like so

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import save
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import ResetTool, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure

x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save,box_select"

p1 = figure(title="Legend Example", tools=TOOLS, x_range=(0, 4 * np.pi), y_range=(-3, 3))
p1.circle(x, y, legend_label="sin(x)")
p1.circle(x, 2 * y, legend_label="2*sin(x)", color="orange")
p1.circle(x, 3 * y, legend_label="3*sin(x)", color="green")

p1.legend.title = "Markers"

p2 = figure(title="Another Legend Example", tools=TOOLS, x_range=(0, 4 * np.pi), y_range=(-3, 3))
p2.circle(x, y, legend_label="sin(x)")
p2.line(x, y, legend_label="sin(x)")

p2.line(
    x,
    2 * y,
    legend_label="2*sin(x)",
    line_dash=(4, 4),
    line_color="orange",
    line_width=2,
)

p2.square(x, 3 * y, legend_label="3*sin(x)", fill_color=None, line_color="green")
p2.line(x, 3 * y, legend_label="3*sin(x)", line_color="green")

p2.legend.title = "Lines"
p2.x_range = p1.x_range

# Add ResetTool to the plot tools
p1.add_tools(ResetTool())
p2.add_tools(ResetTool())

# Define CustomJS callback function to store the zoom levels in local storage
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(p1=p1, p2=p2), code="""
    localStorage.setItem('p1_x_range', JSON.stringify(p1.x_range.start + ',' + p1.x_range.end));
    localStorage.setItem('p1_y_range', JSON.stringify(p1.y_range.start + ',' + p1.y_range.end));
    localStorage.setItem('p2_x_range', JSON.stringify(p2.x_range.start + ',' + p2.x_range.end));
    localStorage.setItem('p2_y_range', JSON.stringify(p2.y_range.start + ',' + p2.y_range.end));
""")

# Add the callback to the ResetTool
for plot in [p1, p2]:
    plot.tools[-1].js_on_change('reset', callback)

# Load the zoom levels from local storage if available
p1_x_range = localStorage.getItem('p1_x_range')
if p1_x_range is not None:
    p1.x_range.start, p1.x_range.end = map(float, p1_x_range.split(','))
    p1.y_range.start, p1.y_range.end = map(float, localStorage.getItem('p1_y_range').split(','))

p2_x_range = localStorage.getItem('p2_x_range')
if p2_x_range is not None:
    p2.x_range.start, p2.x_range.end = map(float, p2_x_range.split(','))
    p2.y_range.start, p2.y_range.end = map(float, localStorage.getItem('p2_y_range').split(','))

save(gridplot([p1, p2], ncols=2, width=400, height=400))
```

In this code, a `ResetTool` was added to each plot and defined a `CustomJS` callback that stores the x and y ranges of each plot in the browser's local storage when the `ResetTool` is used.

Then the callback was added to the `ResetTool` for each plot and loaded the x and y ranges from local storage if they are available.

Note that default values added for the x and y ranges when creating each plot to ensure that the plots have the same range when they are first displayed, even if no zooming has been done yet.

With this modification, the zoom levels for each plot will be saved and restored the next time the HTML file is opened, allowing the user to resume their work where they left off.

Hope it helps

We need to embed the Bokeh plot in a simple HTML file and open it in a web browser. Here's an example HTML file that loads the Bokeh plot and executes the required JavaScript code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bokeh Plot with Zoom Persistence</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-2.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-gl-2.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="plot"></div>
  <script>
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'plot.html', true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var div = document.getElementById('plot');
      div.innerHTML = this.responseText;
      var doc = new Bokeh.Document();
      Bokeh.embed.add_document_standalone(doc);
      doc.from_json(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      // Add the JavaScript code to save and restore the zoom level
      var p1 = doc.get_model_by_name('p1');
      var p2 = doc.get_model_by_name('p2');
      var callback = function() {
        localStorage.setItem('p1_zoom', p1.plot_width / p1.inner_width);
        localStorage.setItem('p2_zoom', p2.plot_width / p2.inner_width);
      };
      p1.js_on_event('reset', callback);
      p2.js_on_event('reset', callback);
      p1.js_on_event('zoom', callback);
      p2.js_on_event('zoom', callback);
      var p1_zoom = localStorage.getItem('p1_zoom');
      if (p1_zoom != null) {
        p1.plot_width = p1_zoom * p1.inner_width;
      }
      var p2_zoom = localStorage.getItem('p2_zoom');
      if (p2_zoom != null) {
        p2.plot_width = p2_zoom * p2.inner_width;
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This HTML file loads the Bokeh plot from a separate file named plot.html, which contains only the gridplot code. The XMLHttpRequest object is used to load the plot.html file asynchronously. Once the file is loaded, the Bokeh plot is added to the document and the required JavaScript code is executed to save and restore the zoom level. To use this HTML file, save it and the updated Python script in the same directory. Then, open the HTML file in a web browser to view the Bokeh plot.

I hope you this will help)

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, it does not work for me. The `localStorage` in the python code is undefined. Could you please check it?

Comment: Sure, if you're encountering the error "localStorage is undefined", it means that the localStorage object is not defined in the current context, this happens when the code is being executed outside of a browser context. So, execute the code in a browser environment.

Comment: My actual use case is running the Python code in a dedicated python virtual environment to generate an html-file containing multiple figures. Then the user open the html-file on his laptop with a browser (e.g. Google Chrome), then zoom-in a bit, close the browser, and open the browser again hoping to see the last zoomed-status. Could you please be more specific, how to execute the code in a browser environment?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value for 'match_aspect' to 'TRUE' within figures on Bokeh will cause any zooming done to be remembered the next time the HTML document is viewed. That's all you have to do.

Comment: I use the code `p1 = figure(title="Legend Example", tools=TOOLS, match_aspect=True)` and `p2 = figure(title="Another Legend Example!", tools=TOOLS, match_aspect=True)`, but it does not work. When I reopen the html file, the 2 figures are all reset.